# How To Use Font Awesome In AMP WordPress Template

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I have a WordPress website and use the "AMP for WordPress" plugin.

In the article from my website I use the icon from Fontawesome. If I open the site using the desktop, fontawesome works fine, but when I try to use my phone and display it in the AMP, the fontawesome icon does not show.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe if the integration with the font-awesome fonts is done correctly, the plugin which you have installed should not conflict with this.

There's a handful of hooks (source: https://ampforwp.com/tutorials/article/hooks-in-ampforwp/) that the AMP plugin contains, specifically the one below which I'm hooking onto (amp_post_template_data). If you add something like this within your functions.php file of your theme, the plugin should know how to utilize the fonts accordingly:

```
add_filter( 'amp_post_template_data', function( $data ) {
    $data['font_urls'] = array(
        'fontawesome' => 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com...';
    );
    return $data;
} );
```

Be sure to replace the actual URL with the font-awesome URL, or your localized file if you have one installed on your theme. Good luck! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom fonts easily try this-

```
add_filter( 'amp_post_template_data', 'wp_amp_add_font_awesome_icons' );
function wp_amp_add_font_awesome_icons( $data ) 
{
    $data['font_urls']['fontawesome'] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
    return $data;
}
```